# Detecting string starting with expression and case-insensitive

Tags: iphone, case-insensitive

In my iPhone app I'm actually detecting text/html content type before showing data in an UIWebView or UITextView.

I detect this with a ContentType variable starting with "text/html", full variable looks like "text/html; charset=utf-8".

So for the moment I use this :

```
if (myContentType hasPrefix:@"text/html")
```

This is fine, but case-sensitive !

So when I have a "TEXT/HTML" content type, that doesn't work.

Is there a way to have the "hasPrefix" method getting case-insensitive ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are dealing with relative small strings, a quick method could be to convert myContentType to lower case before doing the comparison.

Comment: Thanks this is simpler than Vladimir's answer. Then I do this -> if ([myContentType lowercaseString] hasPrefix:@"text/html")

Answer (score 11):

You can use `rangeOfString:options:` function:

```
NSRange range = [myContentType rangeOfString:@"text/html" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch| NSAnchoredSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works fine but Claus Broch's solution is simpler.

Comment: This is the right answer. Converting to lowercase is a workaround